# HashVerificationFilter and "message hash or MAC not valid" exception

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++

In Crpto++ one can easily use pipeline to hash an input.

```
std::string out;
CryptoPP::SHA256 sha;
CryptoPP::StringSource ss(input,true,
                          new CryptoPP::HashFilter(sha,
                              new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(
                                  new CryptoPP::StringSink(out))));
```

Now inorder to verify a gives message x produces the same hash output, I would like to use HashVerificationFilter. I have tried it but it doesn't work. Anyone know the correct syntax ?

```
const int flags = CryptoPP::HashVerificationFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION | CryptoPP::HashVerificationFilter::HASH_AT_END;
CryptoPP::SHA256 sha;
try
{
    CryptoPP::StringSource ss(input + out, true,
                              new CryptoPP::HashVerificationFilter(sha, NULL , flags));
}
catch(const CryptoPP::Exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

I get the output :

```
HashVerificationFilter: message hash or MAC not valid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> std::string out;
> SHA256 sha;
> StringSource ss(input,true,
>     new HashFilter(sha,
>         new HexEncoder(
>             new StringSink(out)
> )));
> ```

You [HexEncode](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexEncoder) your hash. You need to decode it before passing it to the filter:

> ```
> StringSource ss(input + out, true,
>     new HashVerificationFilter(sha, NULL , flags)
> );
> ```

Or, remove the encoding filter:

> ```
> std::string out;
> SHA256 sha;
> StringSource ss(input,true,
>     new HashFilter(sha,
>         new StringSink(out)
> ));
> ```

Comment: Removing the Hex encoder worked. I didn't need it in the first place.